# Removal of React wrapper div

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem after using this this.setState to update the object.

It seems like my object is getting updated with the new one after changing state, but then it returns to a function which is called by render, which is mapping the "view" of my component.

It seem like map function suddenly turn to undefined when it get back to re-render.

What can have happen ? Seem like my component just got lost of the map function

```
Error log:

    SearchResult.tsx:113 Uncaught TypeError: testStories.map is not a function
        at SearchResult.renderStoriesResults (SearchResult.tsx:113)
        at SearchResult.renderShowResults (SearchResult.tsx:192)
        at SearchResult.render (SearchResult.tsx:211)
        at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13194)
        at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13156)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13825)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15864)
        at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15903)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
    SearchResult.renderStoriesResults @ SearchResult.tsx:113
    SearchResult.renderShowResults @ SearchResult.tsx:192
    SearchResult.render @ SearchResult.tsx:211
    finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:13194
    updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:13156
    beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:13825
    performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:15864
    workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:15903
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
    invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
    replayUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:15311
    renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:15963
    performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16561
    performWork @ react-dom.development.js:16483
    performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:16455
    interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16720
    interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2150
    dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4533
    react-dom.development.js:14227 The above error occurred in the <SearchResult> component:
        in SearchResult

    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
boundaries.
    logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:14227
    logError @ react-dom.development.js:14266
    update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:14919
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:10879
    commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:10923
    commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:14397
    commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:15463
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
    invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
    commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:15604
    completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16619
    performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16564
    performWork @ react-dom.development.js:16483
    performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:16455
    interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16720
    interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2150
    dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4533
    SearchResult.tsx:113 Uncaught TypeError: testStories.map is not a function
        at SearchResult.renderStoriesResults (SearchResult.tsx:113)
        at SearchResult.renderShowResults (SearchResult.tsx:192)
        at SearchResult.render (SearchResult.tsx:211)
        at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13194)
        at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13156)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13825)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15864)
        at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15903)
        at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:15943)
        at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16561)
```

Comment: Could you please provide code examples?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the second line of your error trace.

```
SearchResult.tsx:113 Uncaught TypeError: testStories.map is not a function
```

To give an example:

```js
let foo = {}; 
foo.map(); //"Uncaught TypeError: foo.map is not a function",
```

So it's fairly straight forward, the object you're referencing here (testStories) exists, but doesn't have a function called `.map`.

Be aware that [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function of Array, and not of [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: Ah, then how am I able to fix this? :)

Somehow the same object worked in another component I created, but somehow this one didn't...

It is mapped fine on the first iteration, but not on the second when it want to re-render...